# How do plurals work in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

While using [Sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) and reading [the Sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/), I observed that sometimes model names are used in singular and sometimes in plural. Some methods automatically added to models by associations have the singular form and some have the plural form.

**1.** How does Sequelize compute the plurals? Does it simply append an "s" to the string?

**2.** What if I want to use a noun with an irregular plural, such as "Person"?

**3.** When defining an instance, should I use the singular or the plural form?

**4.** When defining an alias, should I use the singular or the plural form?

**5.** When defining a Many-to-many relationship, should I use the singular or the plural form in the `through` option?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## How Sequelize computes plurals

Under the hood, sequelize uses an awesome library called [inflection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inflection) to compute singular and plural forms of words, which works with virtually any english word, including irregular plurals such as `"Person" -> "People"`, `"Octopus" -> "Octopi"`, `"Tooth" -> "Teeth"`. There are a few words that inflection gets wrong though, and for those cases, or cases in which you want to force your custom singular/plural words, see the next topic.

---

## What if I want to use a noun with an irregular plural?

As said above, most words with irregular plurals will be pluralized correctly by inflection (including "Person"). But there are a few words that inflection gets wrong. Sequelize allows you
to force the singular and plural forms you wish, usually accepting a plain object with the form `{ singular: "your-singular-here", plural: "your-plural-here" }` in place of the name string. See the next topics for more details.

---

## When defining an instance

When defining an instance, the standard way is to use the singular name, but you can also use the plural name, since sequelize will apply inflection methods on it to get the singular and plural form
whenever needed:

```
const Foo = sequelize.define("foo", {
    // attributes
});
```

If you want to force your custom singular and plural forms, use the third parameter to specify the name option:

```
const Foo = sequelize.define("foo", {
    // attributes
}, {
    name: {
        singular: "mycustomsingularstring",
        plural: "mycustompluralstring"
    }
});
```

---

## When defining an alias

When defining an alias for a `hasOne` or `belongsTo` association, you must use the singular form:

```
Foo.belongsTo(Bar, { as: "person" });
```

When defining an alias for a `hasMany` or `belongsToMany` association, you must use the plural form:

```
Foo.belongsToMany(Bar, { through: Foo_Bar, as: "people" });
```

Or, if you want to force your custom singular/plural strings:

```
Foo.belongsToMany(Bar, {
    through: Foo_Bar,
    as: {
        singular: "mycustomsingularstring",
        plural: "mycustompluralstring"
    }
});
```

---

## When defining a Many-to-many relationship

If you have a sequelize model for the junction table itself, the best practice is to use the model itself in the `through` option:

```
// If you have this somewhere
const Foo_Bar = sequelize.define("foo_bar", {
    // attributes
});

// Then the best practice is to pass the model itself
Foo.belongsToMany(Bar, { through: Foo_Bar });
```

If you don't have a sequelize model for the junction table itself, which is not unusual (you are letting sequelize do the many-to-many magic by itself), then you must use the plural form:

```
Foo.belongsToMany(Bar, { through: "foo_bars" });
```

---

<sub>By the way, you might have noticed that all model definitions in my examples are lowercase, this is to follow a convention from PostgreSQL (if you have uppercase letters in your tables in PostgreSQL you might have problems), but if you're not using PostgreSQL you're probably fine to use uppercase characters in your model names.</sub>

Comment: to be frank they should honestly have not added this, why do they want to make decisions on behalf of the user what the tablename would be called, this has complicated maintenance of their lib

Comment: @PirateApp Hello, I've become a maintainer now, in the future I might start some changes to move towards changing this default behavior!

Comment: Im really getting irritated with this singular and plural thing and its confusing as to where which has to be used. Its making the entire usage cumbersome and waste of time

Comment: @ShyamSundarR Hi, sorry to hear that you're having trouble, thank you for letting me know, perhaps we can add an option to disable this altogether. However, ideally we would want plurals to be applied on places where it does make sense, of course we don't want peopke's time to be wasted, can you please open an issue showing a minimal example in which this bothered you? Thanks!

Comment: @PedroA, Im a very new person trying to get around this package very recently maybe about a week back. I basically was trying to look into github's existing packages for some sample code. I generally know the general db principles and have worked with mongoose and mongo. I mean Im basically confused at places where we define models, the migrations createtable method. Multiple places are there. I also never could really understand when the models js files will be used, , will it be internally used to restrain data which are migrated to those models? really not interested to go through full docs

Comment: @PedroA, there are a multiple methods I find to define a model. When I auto generate it using CLI I get something that uses classes. In another way I can do it using sequelize.define method. Which exactly is the right way to define a model. Lot of confusing stuff.

Comment: Hi @ShyamSundarR, take a look at our [express-example](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/tree/master/express-main-example), it might help. Indeed I need to improve the documentation on all this. About using classes versus using `sequelize.define`, both work. You can choose what you like the most.

Comment: @PedroA, ya I had a look on that. Things seems to be pretty convincing. But what exactly is the need to maintain 2 separate folders, models and migrations, when both almost contain the same data model.

Comment: @PedroA, also your github repo doesnt have anything like migrations, seeders and all. I was expecting some properly working sample code.