# Change Sequelize default foreign key with through tables

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, orm, sequelize.js

I have two tables, `apps` and `services`. On `services` the PRIMARY KEY is set to field called `orn`.
I created a through table between these two tables called `apps_services` with `appId` and `serviceId`

```
 appId: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        references: {
          model: 'apps',
          key: 'id'
        }
      },

      serviceId: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        references: {
          model: 'services',
          key: 'orn'
        }
      },
```

But here is a problem, when i use `app.addService(foundService);` (this creates a relationship between that app instance and foundService). When i used node debugger, i found out that sequelize tried inserting an `id` into `serviceId` instead of an `orn`

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "apps_services" ("id","appId","serviceId","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES ('8d85f9b9-b472-4165-a345-657a0fe0d8ad','49f3daa4-1df4-4890-92f8-9a06f751ffb7','8cab340d-d11b-4e3b-842c-aeea9a28c368','2021-02-16 00:22:17.919 +00:00','2021-02-16 00:22:17.919 +00:00') RETURNING "id","appId","serviceId","userId","selfGranted","createdAt","updatedAt";
```

the third value in the bracket, the problem is `id` is not the foreignKey but `orn` is

below is the `service` table, we can see the `orn` column, which is the PRIMARY KEY and foreign key linking to the apps_services table.

Is there a way to force sequelize to use the `orn` field?

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const apps_services = sequelize.define('apps_services', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: new DataTypes.UUIDV4(),
        unique: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    appId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
    },

    serviceId: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID
    },
    selfGranted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

apps_services.associate = function (models) {
    models.apps.belongsToMany(models.services, {
        through: apps_services
    });

    models.services.belongsToMany(models.apps, {
        through: apps_services
    });
};
//apps_services.sync({alter: true});

return apps_services;
```

};

// this is apps_services migration

```
module.exports = {
up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
 await queryInterface.createTable('apps_services', {
   id:{
     type: Sequelize.UUID,
     defaultValue: new Sequelize.UUIDV4(),
     unique: true,
     primaryKey: true
 },
   appId: {
     type: Sequelize.UUID,
     references: {
       model: 'apps',
       key: 'id'
     }
   },

   serviceId: {
     type: Sequelize.STRING,
     references: {
       model: 'services',
       key: 'orn'
     }
   },

   userId: {
     type: Sequelize.UUID,
     references: {
       model: 'Users',
       key: 'id'
     }
   },

   createdAt: {
     allowNull: false,
     type: Sequelize.DATE
   },
   updatedAt: {
     allowNull: false,
     type: Sequelize.DATE
   },
   selfGranted: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
 });
},

down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
 await queryInterface.dropTable('apps_services');
}
};
```

Below is the services table

[image: we can see the orn there]

Comment: Please add model files in the question, so its easy to understand and can help you better.

Comment: @AbhishekShah i have added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can mention which field to use from the opposite table.

```js
apps_services.associate = function (models) {
    
    // you can move this association to apps model file
    models.apps.belongsToMany(models.services, {
        // Reference: https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-belongsToMany
        through: 'apps_services',
        foreignKey: 'appId', // <-- add this
    });
    
    // you can move this association to services model file
    models.services.belongsToMany(models.apps, {
        through: 'apps_services',
        foreignKey: 'serviceId', // <-- add this - name of field in through table
        otherKey: 'orn', // <-- add this - name of field in source table
    });
    
    /**
     * new relation below just to complete the Many to Many relation
     */
    // you can add this association in app_services model file
    models.apps_services.belongsTo(models.services, {
        // Reference: https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-belongsTo
        foreignKey: 'serviceId', // <--- name of field in source table
        targetKey: 'orn', // <--- name of field in target table
    });
    
    // you can add this association in app_services model file
    models.apps_services.belongsTo(models.apps, {
        foreignKey: 'appId', // <--- name of field in source table
        // targetKey: 'id', //(not needed as already primary key by default) <--- name of field in target table
    });

};
```

Comment: i did these, but when i ran
```apps_services.sync({alter: true});```

on the output on the terminal , i saw this

```Executing (default): ALTER TABLE "apps_services"  ADD FOREIGN KEY ("serviceId") REFERENCES "services" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;```

it is still linking ```serviceId``` to ```id``` on services table

Comment: i have solved it now, i have no idea what sequelize was trying to do, but it seems as if it decides what to link to foreignKey from the name of the foreignKey. If there's ``Id`` in the name like ``serviceId`` it just tries to link it to the ``id`` field during ``set()``.

What i did was change the name to ``serviceOrn`` and instead of ``otherKey : 'orn'`` i used ``sourceKey: 'orn'``