# Multiple images + Node.js + Sequelize + Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I want an association in Sequelize + node.js and MySQL database where `Product.hasMany(images)` and also `images.belongsTo(Product)`. I want to upload multiple images to database.

I am done with uploading multiple images to AWS S3. But i want to store the returned link of those images to the database. I am unable to do with such relation since adding the links of all images to database at the same time is not possible for me. All I want is to add the different images to each rows of the table along with the product id that it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how AWS S3 uploads files(images), but I think logic is same as below

```
let images = [];
// to see if files field exist
if(req.files) {
  // logic to save url in db
  for (let i=0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
    let image = await Image.create(req.files[i])
    images.push(image)
  }
} 
// will assume req.body has required fields
const product = await Product.create(req.body)
// here use association mixins
await product.addImages(images);
```

To learn more about association mixins check out this link [stackoverflow-question-about-sequelize-mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49467654/what-methods-mixins-sequelize-adds-to-the-models-when-an-association-is-made)