# How to set extra attributes of through model on creation in SequelizeJS?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

**My models:**

```
 Recipe (id, name)
 Ingredient (id, name)
 Recipe_Ingredient (recipeId, ingredientId, quantity)
```

**My associations:**

```
Recipe.belongsToMany(Ingredient, { through: Recipe_Ingredient })
Ingredient.belongsToMany(Recipe, { through: Recipe_Ingredient })
```

**My problem:**

How can I create a Recipe with some Ingredients and the quantities attached to them?

**I tried:**

```
Recipe.create({
  name: 'Pizza',
  ingredients:[
    {
      name: 'mozarella',
      recipe_ingredients: {
          quantity: 5
      }
    }
  ]
}, {
    include:[Ingredient]
})
```

Records are created for Recipe, Ingredient and the Recipe_Ingredient. The only problem is that the value of the quantity is not collected from the data source.

Comment: What if you specify the `through` in the create? `include:[ { model: Ingredient, through: Recipe_Ingredient } ]`.

Comment: Might also want to try `receipe_ingredient` (not plural) since it's not an array...

Comment: @doublesharp that is not working, also the table names are frozen so there is no issue with the plural

Comment: I believe you will need to update your `include`: `{
  include: [{
    association: Ingredient,
    include: [ Recipe_Ingredient ]
  }]
}`

Comment: @mcranston18 I tried but it is not really working. Do you have an working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not possible to do this in the past, but in October 23, 2018 this was fixed in sequelize [PR #10050](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/10050).

As of today (2018-10-24) the fix is not released yet, but as soon as `v5.0.0-beta14` comes out, you'll be able to do the following:

```
Recipe.create({
    name: 'Pizza',
    ingredients: [
        {
            name: 'mozarella',
            recipe_ingredient: {
                quantity: 5
            }
        }
    ]
}, {
    include: Ingredient
})
```

Also, note that the correct usage is `recipe_ingredient:` in the singular form, not in the plural form as you tried in your question. This makes sense, because for a given Ingredient, associated with a given Recipe, there is only one Recipe_Ingredient involved, always.

If you do not want to wait for `v5.0.0-beta14` (although it will probably be released very soon), you can install it directly from github's `master` branch as follows:

`npm install --save https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/tarball/master`

Answer (score 1):

A solution I found, inspired by answers of pedro around here ([How do I ORM additional columns on a join table in sequelize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957191/how-do-i-orm-additional-columns-on-a-join-table-in-sequelize/49216302?noredirect=1#comment92505692_49216302)) and there is given by a change of perspective.

```
receipe (name:string)
ingredient (quantity:int)
type (name: string)

receipe.hasMany(ingredient, {as:'ingredients'} )
ingredient.belongsTo(type)
```

and then I can consume data like this:

```
receipe.create({
  name: 'Pizza',
  ingredients:[
    {
      quantity: 5,
      type: {
         name: 'ingredient 1'
      }
    }, {
      quantity: 6,
      type: {
         name: 'ingredient 2'
      }
    } {
      quantity: 5,
      type_id: 1
    }]
}, {
    include:[{
       model; ingredient,
       as: 'ingredients',
       include:[{
         model: type
       }]
    }]
})
```

It has some drawbacks but it is good enough for me.

*One problem* can be that if you add two items of the same new type, you will get a unique key violation (as types are unique and sequelize will not try to search if the type exists before trying to create it).

*Another problem* is that if you specify just the type_id in the data, it will not actually return the type refereed by that in the result.

Comment: Hello! Nice solution. I like the change of perspective you did here. But I also agree with you that it would be better if it just worked in the way you imagined in the first place. By the way, while investigating for other solutions I tested a few things and stumbled in a weird error message in one of my attempts, and opened an issue about it: [#10034](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10034). Let's see :)

Comment: By the way, in your question you tried `receipe_ingredients: { quantity: 5 }` but to me `receipe_ingredient: { quantity: 5 }` (in singular) makes more sense (although none of them worked anyway).

Comment: Hey @PedroA! Thanks, let s see if there is a solution for that! :)